# Regular expression a captured group with 1 to 5 ords

Tags: c#, regex

I have a sentence like 'This is [[a captured group]].'  The number of words between the captured can be 1 to 5.

I want to pick out everything between the two brackets (including the brackets).  I know I could use something like `@"^.*(?<identifier>\[\[\.*\]\]).*$"` but I want to try to be more precise so I thought this would work: `@"^.*(?<identifier>\[\[\w*(\b\w*){0,4}\]\]).*$"`

Can anyone see why this doesn't work? It captures if there's one word as in between the brackets but not multiple.  I thought the `(\b\w*){0,4}` would allow for 0 to 4 more words.

Thanks, Bill N

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create more than one captured groups, one per bracket. Try this:

```
@"^.*(?<identifier>\[\[\w*(?:\s\w*){0,4}\]\]).*$"
```

`(?:)` This is a non capturing group, that not creates a variable, so that your result is still in the named group.

Update: And of course as the two other answers pointed out, your main problem is the missing `\s` I added this also to my solution.

Update2: The `\b` is not needed when the `\s` is added, so removed.

Comment: You added `\s` between two optional word characters. And why do you need the `\b` ?

Answer (score 3):

I think you forget about word delimeters (`\s`):

```
^.*(?<identifier>\[\[\w+(\s+\b\w+){0,4}\]\]).*$
```

Comment: Why not just `(\w+(?:\s+|(?=\]))){1,5}`, and why do you need `\b` ?

Answer (score 2):

You problem is here:

```
(\b\w*){0,4}
```

This would not work since you have not allowed for **spaces**. Change it to:

```
(\s+\b\w*){0,4}
```

This will capture spaces but you can easily post-process (using `Trim()`).

Comment: `\s*` does not mean anything. It will always capture (i.e. it is actually `+\s`) since there is always going to be space delimiter - **according to the question**.

Answer (score 0):

My preference would be something like this  (untested):

`^[^\[]*(?<identifier>\[\[\s*(\w+(?:\s+|(?=\]))){1,5}\]\])[\S\s]*$`

```
^                           # begin of string
 [^\[]*                      # some optional not '[' chars
 (?<identifier>              # <ID> begin
    \[\[                        # '[['
         \s*                             # some optional whitespace
         (?:\w+ (?:\s+|(?=\])) ){1,5}    # 1-5 words separated by spaces
    \]\]                        # ']]'
 )                           # end <ID>
 [\S\s]*                     # some optional any chars
$ 
                     # end of string
```